# Sort the queryset in an arbitrary order

Tags: python, django

I have such a template to present the blocks from database

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <a style='font-size:18pt' href="article/list/{{ b.id }}">{{ b.name }}</a>
    <span class='pull-right'>{{ b.admin }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    {{ b.desc }}
  </div>
</div>
```

the data model:

```
class Block(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (1,  'normal'),
        (0, 'deleted'),
    )
    name = models.CharField("block name", max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField("block description", max_length=100)
    admin = models.CharField("block admin", max_length=100)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("id",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I retrieve the data as

```
In [2]: from article.models import Block
In [3]: blocks = Block.objects.all()
In [4]: blocks
Out[4]: <QuerySet [<Block: Concepts>, <Block: Reading>, <Block: Coding>, <Block: Action>]>
```

I want to present the data as an arbitrary order of  `['concept','code', 'read', 'action']` rather than by id,

By observing, I find that this could achieved by order its second letter,

```
In [7]: sorted(l, key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)
Out[7]: ['concept', 'code', 'read', 'action']
```

How could sort the queryset this way?

Comment: This is a bad database model design as you are hardcoding row `values` of the `name` column in your codebase. For arbitrary ordering just include a new `rank` integer column in your model and sort using that. Or you can use `Case` `When` `Then` Django's construct to annotate the value of `rank` should you choose that it's okay to hardcode name values.

Comment: @ArpitSingh: I think you misread the question. These are *sample* values for the rows...

Comment: OP used the words `By observing`. I am still not sure if OP actually wants ordering by 2nd letter or was just trying to get his/her point across better. It's not usually required ever in the real world to sort a list by second character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first annotate every `Block` instance, and then order by this annotation that uses the [**`Substr`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Substr), like:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Substr

Block.objects.annotate(
    sndchar=Substr('name', 2, 1)
).order_by('-sndchar')
```

as extra bonus every `Block` instance will have a `sndchar` attribute which is the second character of the `name` attribute (only in this queryset). But that is not really a problem I think. In case it clashes with another column, you can rename it.

The minus char in `-sndchar` means that we will sort in descending order. You can remove it if you want to sort in ascending order.

The sorting is thus here done at the database level, which is usually (significantly) faster than doing this at the Django level.

You can also sort on the string *starting* from the second character (such that in case of a *tie*, the third character, etc. is taken into account), by dropping the `length` parameter, and thus annotate with the name except the first character:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Substr

# This will sort on the third character in case of a tie, and so on
Block.objects.annotate(
    sndchar=Substr('name', 2)
).order_by('-sndchar')
```

Comment: The question states `an arbitrary order`. This is not arbitrary, it's a sort on the second character of `name`

Comment: @ArpitSingh: well if you read the question entirely, you will notice that later, it states that the elements should be sorted by the *second character*.

Answer (score 5):

Using Django's [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value, When

array = ['concept', 'code', 'read', 'action']

Block.objects.annotate(
    rank=Case(
        *[When(name=name, then=Value(array.index(name))) for name in array],
        default=Value(len(array)),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ),
).order_by('rank')
```